# How to filter Map by a List using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to change the following code to use `Stream`s, but I didn't find a similar example.

```
Map<Integer, DspInfoEntity> dspInfoEntityMap = dspInfoService.getDspInfoEntityMap();
List<DspInfoEntity> dspInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
for (AppLaunchMappingDto appLaunchMappingDto : appLaunchMappingDtoList) {
    int dspId = appLaunchMappingDto.getDspId();
    if (dspInfoEntityMap.containsKey(dspId)) {
        dspInfoList.add(dspInfoEntityMap.get(dspId));
    }
}
```

I think it could be like this:

```
List<DspInfoEntity> dspInfoList = dspInfoEntityMap.entrySet().stream().filter(?).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your imperative code filters **a list**: appLaunchMappingDtoList. That's also what the functional code should do.

Comment: You're iterate over a `List` not over a `Map` in `dspInfoEntityMap.entrySet()` or I'm wrong with that?

Comment: Perhaps`filter(dspInfoEntityMap::containsKey).mapToObj(dspInfoEntityMap::get)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop filters the `appLaunchMappingDtoList` list, so you should stream over the List, not the Map:

```
List<DspInfoEntity> dspInfoList = 
    appLaunchMappingDtoList.stream() // Stream<AppLaunchMappingDto>
                           .map(AppLaunchMappingDto::getDspId) // Stream<Integer>
                           .map(dspInfoEntityMap::get) // Stream<DspInfoEntity>
                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<DspInfoEntity>
```

or (if your `Map` may contain null values and you don't want to filter them out):

```
List<DspInfoEntity> dspInfoList = 
    appLaunchMappingDtoList.stream() // Stream<AppLaunchMappingDto>
                           .map(AppLaunchMappingDto::getDspId) // Stream<Integer>
                           .filter(dspInfoEntityMap::containsKey)
                           .map(dspInfoEntityMap::get) // Stream<DspInfoEntity>
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<DspInfoEntity>
```